# How to determine if a File Matches a File Mask?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to decide whether file name fits to file mask. The file mask could contain * or ? characters. Is there any simple solution for this?

```
bool bFits = Fits("myfile.txt", "my*.txt");

private bool Fits(string sFileName, string sFileMask)
    {
        ??? anything simple here ???
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
private bool FitsMask(string sFileName, string sFileMask)
{
    Regex mask = new Regex(sFileMask.Replace(".", "[.]").Replace("*", ".*").Replace("?", "."));
    return mask.IsMatch(sFileName);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't handle '?' (need to convert to ".").

Comment: Now it is almost fine. There should be Regex instead of RegEx and I had to add using System.Text.RegularExpressions; into usings.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If you're looking at windows then this isn't right. For example given the mask "*.asp" it will match "foo.asp" and "foo.aspx" and "foo.aspxx", however given the mask  "*.aspx" it will only mask "foo.aspx". There are special rules for three-character extensions.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good solution.  Given the mask "jpg", pic.jpg passes.  I'd expect "*.jpg" to match.

Comment: Ok, now let's try to match file file$name.com with mask * $ *.com. The regexp will be .*$.*[.]com and it won't match filename. So, you have to escape all these valid characters that have special meaning in Regexp: []()^$+=!{,}

Comment: You can just start off by using Regex.Escape()

Comment: @Nyderguds poses an alternative solution which I recommend people scroll down to find.

Answer (score 32):

I appreciate finding Joel's answer--saved me some time as well ! I did, however, have to make a few changes to make the method do what most users would expect:

- I removed the 'this' keyword preceding the first argument. It does nothing here (though it could be useful if the method is intended to be an extension method, in which case it needs to be public and contained within a static class and itself be a static method).
- I made the regular expression case-independent to match standard Windows wildcard behavior (so e.g. "c*.*" and "C*.*" both return the same result).
- I added starting and ending anchors to the regular expression, again to match standard Windows wildcard behavior (so e.g. "stuff.txt" would be matched by "stuff*" or "s*" or "s*.*" but not by just "s").

---

```
private bool FitsMask(string fileName, string fileMask)
{
    Regex mask = new Regex(
        '^' + 
        fileMask
            .Replace(".", "[.]")
            .Replace("*", ".*")
            .Replace("?", ".")
        + '$',
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return mask.IsMatch(fileName);
}
```

### 2009.11.04 Update: Match one of several masks

For even more flexibility, here is a plug-compatible method built on top of the original. This version lets you pass multiple masks (hence the plural on the second parameter name *fileMasks*) separated by lines, commas, vertical bars, or spaces. I wanted it so that I could let the user put as many choices as desired in a ListBox and then select all files matching *any* of them. Note that some controls (like a ListBox) use CR-LF for line breaks while others (e.g. RichTextBox) use just LF--that is why both "\r\n" and "\n" show up in the Split list.

```
private bool FitsOneOfMultipleMasks(string fileName, string fileMasks)
{
    return fileMasks
        .Split(new string[] {"\r\n", "\n", ",", "|", " "},
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Any(fileMask => FitsMask(fileName, fileMask));
}
```

### 2009.11.17 Update: Handle fileMask inputs more gracefully

The earlier version of FitsMask (which I have left in for comparison) does a fair job but since we are treating it as a regular expression it will throw an exception if it is not a valid regular expression when it comes in. The solution is that we actually want any regex metacharacters in the input fileMask to be considered literals, not metacharacters. But we still need to treat period, asterisk, and question mark specially. So this improved version of FitsMask safely moves these three characters out of the way, transforms all remaining metacharacters into literals, then puts the three interesting characters back, in their "regex'ed" form.

One other minor improvement is to allow for case-independence, per standard Windows behavior.

```
private bool FitsMask(string fileName, string fileMask)
{
    string pattern =
         '^' + 
         Regex.Escape(fileMask.Replace(".", "__DOT__")
                         .Replace("*", "__STAR__")
                         .Replace("?", "__QM__"))
             .Replace("__DOT__", "[.]")
             .Replace("__STAR__", ".*")
             .Replace("__QM__", ".")
         + '$';
    return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(fileName);
}
```

### 2010.09.30 Update: Somewhere along the way, passion ensued...

I have been remiss in not updating this earlier but these references will likely be of interest to readers who have made it to this point:

- I embedded the **FitsMask** method as the heart of a WinForms user control aptly called a **FileMask**--see the API [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/api/csharp/html/T_CleanCode_GeneralComponents_Controls_FileMask.htm).
- I then wrote an article featuring the FileMask control published on Simple-Talk.com, entitled [Using LINQ Lambda Expressions to Design Customizable Generic Components](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/using-linq-lambda-expressions-to-design-customizable-generic-components/). (While the method itself does not use LINQ, the FileMask user control does, hence the title of the article.)

Comment: You still have a problem in your code. All these characters are allowed in file names, but have special meaning in regular expressions: []()^$+=!{,} You need to escape them as you escape dot character.

Comment: That `__DOT__` / `__STAR__` / `__QM__` stuff will still mess up on any filename that just happens to contain one of these special replace strings. Escaping first and then replacing the escaped strings is the only good solution. Especially since (Windows) filenames can't contain \, so escaped \ characters aren't a problem.

Comment: @Nyderguds poses an alternative solution which I recommend people scroll down to find.

Comment: This is the best answer for me. The accepted answer is incomplete. The '^' ... '$' is missing.

Answer (score 17):

Many people don't know that, but .NET includes an internal class, called "PatternMatcher" (under the "System.IO" namespace).

This static class contains only 1 method:
`public static bool StrictMatchPattern(string expression, string name)`

This method is used by .net whenever it needs to compare files with wildcard (FileSystemWatcher, GetFiles(), etc)

Using reflector, I exposed the code here.
Didn't really go through it to understand how it works, but it works great,

So this is the code for anyone who doesn't want to work with the inefficient RegEx way:

```
public static class PatternMatcher
{
    // Fields
    private const char ANSI_DOS_QM = '<';
    private const char ANSI_DOS_STAR = '>';
    private const char DOS_DOT = '"';
    private const int MATCHES_ARRAY_SIZE = 16;

    // Methods
    public static bool StrictMatchPattern(string expression, string name)
    {
        expression = expression.ToLowerInvariant();
        name = name.ToLowerInvariant();
        int num9;
        char ch = '\0';
        char ch2 = '\0';
        int[] sourceArray = new int[16];
        int[] numArray2 = new int[16];
        bool flag = false;
        if (((name == null) || (name.Length == 0)) || ((expression == null) || (expression.Length == 0)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (expression.Equals("*") || expression.Equals("*.*"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if ((expression[0] == '*') && (expression.IndexOf('*', 1) == -1))
        {
            int length = expression.Length - 1;
            if ((name.Length >= length) && (string.Compare(expression, 1, name, name.Length - length, length, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        sourceArray[0] = 0;
        int num7 = 1;
        int num = 0;
        int num8 = expression.Length * 2;
        while (!flag)
        {
            int num3;
            if (num < name.Length)
            {
                ch = name[num];
                num3 = 1;
                num++;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
                if (sourceArray[num7 - 1] == num8)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            int index = 0;
            int num5 = 0;
            int num6 = 0;
            while (index < num7)
            {
                int num2 = (sourceArray[index++] + 1) / 2;
                num3 = 0;
            Label_00F2:
                if (num2 != expression.Length)
                {
                    num2 += num3;
                    num9 = num2 * 2;
                    if (num2 == expression.Length)
                    {
                        numArray2[num5++] = num8;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ch2 = expression[num2];
                        num3 = 1;
                        if (num5 >= 14)
                        {
                            int num11 = numArray2.Length * 2;
                            int[] destinationArray = new int[num11];
                            Array.Copy(numArray2, destinationArray, numArray2.Length);
                            numArray2 = destinationArray;
                            destinationArray = new int[num11];
                            Array.Copy(sourceArray, destinationArray, sourceArray.Length);
                            sourceArray = destinationArray;
                        }
                        if (ch2 == '*')
                        {
                            numArray2[num5++] = num9;
                            numArray2[num5++] = num9 + 1;
                            goto Label_00F2;
                        }
                        if (ch2 == '>')
                        {
                            bool flag2 = false;
                            if (!flag && (ch == '.'))
                            {
                                int num13 = name.Length;
                                for (int i = num; i < num13; i++)
                                {
                                    char ch3 = name[i];
                                    num3 = 1;
                                    if (ch3 == '.')
                                    {
                                        flag2 = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if ((flag || (ch != '.')) || flag2)
                            {
                                numArray2[num5++] = num9;
                                numArray2[num5++] = num9 + 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                numArray2[num5++] = num9 + 1;
                            }
                            goto Label_00F2;
                        }
                        num9 += num3 * 2;
                        switch (ch2)
                        {
                            case '<':
                                if (flag || (ch == '.'))
                                {
                                    goto Label_00F2;
                                }
                                numArray2[num5++] = num9;
                                goto Label_028D;

                            case '"':
                                if (flag)
                                {
                                    goto Label_00F2;
                                }
                                if (ch == '.')
                                {
                                    numArray2[num5++] = num9;
                                    goto Label_028D;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        if (!flag)
                        {
                            if (ch2 == '?')
                            {
                                numArray2[num5++] = num9;
                            }
                            else if (ch2 == ch)
                            {
                                numArray2[num5++] = num9;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            Label_028D:
                if ((index < num7) && (num6 < num5))
                {
                    while (num6 < num5)
                    {
                        int num14 = sourceArray.Length;
                        while ((index < num14) && (sourceArray[index] < numArray2[num6]))
                        {
                            index++;
                        }
                        num6++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (num5 == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            int[] numArray4 = sourceArray;
            sourceArray = numArray2;
            numArray2 = numArray4;
            num7 = num5;
        }
        num9 = sourceArray[num7 - 1];
        return (num9 == num8);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is... bafflingly stupid. Wow. Why wouldn't they expose that? X_x

Comment: I second Nyeguds, it should have been part of the System.IO.Path class!

Comment: The actual source code is published at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2017/06/04/wildcards-in-windows/

Comment: We have sourcecode nowadays: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/io/system/io/PatternMatcher.cs

Answer (score 14):

None of these answers quite seem to do the trick, and msorens's is needlessly complex. This one should work just fine:

```
public static Boolean MatchesMask(string fileName, string fileMask)
{
    String convertedMask = "^" + Regex.Escape(fileMask).Replace("\\*", ".*").Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
    Regex regexMask = new Regex(convertedMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return regexMask.IsMatch(fileName);
}
```

This makes sure possible regex chars in the mask are escaped, replaces the \* and \?, and surrounds it all by ^ and $ to mark the boundaries.

Of course, in most situations, it's far more useful to simply make this into a `FileMaskToRegex` tool function which returns the Regex object, so you just got it once and can then make a loop in which you check all strings from your files list on it.

```
public static Regex FileMaskToRegex(string fileMask)
{
    String convertedMask = "^" + Regex.Escape(fileMask).Replace("\\*", ".*").Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
    return new Regex(convertedMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`WildCardPattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern) class from `System.Management.Automation` available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=System.Management.Automation) or in Windows PowerShell SDK.

```
WildcardPattern pattern = new WildcardPattern("my*.txt");
bool fits = pattern.IsMatch("myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 4):

From Windows 7 using P/Invoke (without 260 char count limit):

```
// UNICODE_STRING for Rtl... method
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct UNICODE_STRING
{
    public ushort Length;
    public ushort MaximumLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string Buffer;

    public UNICODE_STRING(string buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            Length = MaximumLength = 0;
        else
            Length = MaximumLength = unchecked((ushort)(buffer.Length * 2));
        Buffer = buffer;
    }
}

// RtlIsNameInExpression method from NtDll.dll system library
public static class NtDll
{
    [DllImport("NtDll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public extern static bool RtlIsNameInExpression(
        ref UNICODE_STRING Expression,
        ref UNICODE_STRING Name,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        bool IgnoreCase,
        IntPtr Zero
        );
}

public bool MatchMask(string mask, string fileName)
{
    // Expression must be uppercase for IgnoreCase == true (see MSDN for RtlIsNameInExpression)
    UNICODE_STRING expr = new UNICODE_STRING(mask.ToUpper());
    UNICODE_STRING name = new UNICODE_STRING(fileName);

    if (NtDll.RtlIsNameInExpression(ref expr, ref name, true, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        // MATCHES !!!
    }
}
```

Comment: So, why don't you make it actually _return_ the boolean result, rather than adding that `// MATCHES !!!` comment?

Answer (score 3):

Fastest version of the previously proposed function:

```
    public static bool FitsMasks(string filePath, params string[] fileMasks)
            // or
    public static Regex FileMasksToRegex(params string[] fileMasks)
    {
        if (!_maskRegexes.ContainsKey(fileMasks))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("^");
            bool first = true;
            foreach (string fileMask in fileMasks)
            {
                if(first) first =false; else sb.Append("|");
                sb.Append('(');
                foreach (char c in fileMask)
                {
                    switch (c)
                    {
                        case '*': sb.Append(@".*"); break;
                        case '?': sb.Append(@"."); break;
                        default:
                                sb.Append(Regex.Escape(c.ToString()));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                sb.Append(')');
            }
            sb.Append("$");
            _maskRegexes[fileMasks] = new Regex(sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
        return _maskRegexes[fileMasks].IsMatch(filePath);
                    // or
        return _maskRegexes[fileMasks];
    }
    static readonly Dictionary<string[], Regex> _maskRegexes = new Dictionary<string[], Regex>(/*unordered string[] comparer*/);
```

Notes:

1. Re-using Regex objects.
2. Using StringBuilder to optimize Regex creation (multiple .Replace() calls are slow).
3. Multiple masks, combined with OR.
4. Another version returning the Regex.

Comment: In reality, I can imagine this kind of function is normally used on a whole list though, so just making the regex first before the filter loop and then going through the list with `foreach` to use the filter would solve the inefficiency of remaking the regex every time anyway.

Comment: @Nyerguds Agreed. However, the above code can be adapted to produce the Regex object even for looping over multiple files, even if for little performance gain. On a side note, a simple improvement would allow multiple masks to be passed in for an "OR" comparison.

Comment: True. I'd just go for a `Regex FileMaskToRegex(String fileMask)` function though; more generally usable. Oh, another small note on your code: the filtering out of the "." is completely unnecessary: your specific-case code for it does exactly the same as the default case, namely escaping it. You also forgot the `"^"` indicating the _start_ of the expression

Comment: Heh. Well, if you keep the masks stored in that dictionary anyway, returning the Regex object isn't particularly useful. I just meant that returning the regex is generally a good alternative for the dictionary. Still, nice :)

Comment: On a related note, you could further optimize this by sorting the file masks array so you're sure you don't make different regexes for identical but differently-sorted masks lists. Of course, whether such optimization is actually useful depends entirely on the situation.

Comment: @Nyerguds note the `/*unordered string[] comparer*/` comment - I thought of that, hence the `unordered`. Re dictionary, it may still be beneficial, in case where user requests the "search" multiple times - each time a regex has to be retrieved. The dictionary saves times by storing the previously created regex for a particular set of masks. The dictionary storage and lookup may be more expensive than rebuilding the regex, btw - up to the coder to make that decision in their particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

If PowerShell is available, it has direct support for [wildcard type matching](http://msdn.com/library/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern) (as well as Regex).

```
WildcardPattern pat = new WildcardPattern("a*.b*");
if (pat.IsMatch(filename)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to copy the source code and like @frankhommers I came up with a reflection based solution.

Notice the code comment about the use of wildcards in the name argument I found in the reference source.

```
    public static class PatternMatcher
    {
        static MethodInfo strictMatchPatternMethod;
        static PatternMatcher()
        {
            var typeName = "System.IO.PatternMatcher";
            var methodName = "StrictMatchPattern";
            var assembly = typeof(Uri).Assembly;
            var type = assembly.GetType(typeName, true);
            strictMatchPatternMethod = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public) ?? throw new MissingMethodException($"{typeName}.{methodName} not found");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tells whether a given name matches the expression given with a strict (i.e. UNIX like) semantics.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expression">Supplies the input expression to check against</param>
        /// <param name="name">Supplies the input name to check for.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool StrictMatchPattern(string expression, string name)
        {
            // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/io/system/io/PatternMatcher.cs
            // If this class is ever exposed for generic use,
            // we need to make sure that name doesn't contain wildcards. Currently 
            // the only component that calls this method is FileSystemWatcher and
            // it will never pass a name that contains a wildcard.
            if (name.Contains('*')) throw new FormatException("Wildcard not allowed");
            return (bool)strictMatchPatternMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { expression, name });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For .net Core the way microsoft [does](https://github.com/ianhays/corefx/blob/21e73c6b703946032a61cd639c2ba7662b319785/src/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher/src/System/IO/FileSystemWatcher.cs#L384).

```
        private bool MatchPattern(ReadOnlySpan<char> relativePath)
        {
            ReadOnlySpan<char> name = IO.Path.GetFileName(relativePath);
            if (name.Length == 0)
                return false;

            if (Filters.Count == 0)
                return true;

            foreach (string filter in Filters)
            {
                if (FileSystemName.MatchesSimpleExpression(filter, name, ignoreCase: !PathInternal.IsCaseSensitive))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

The way microsoft itself seemed to do for .NET 4.6 is documented in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/17b97365645da62cf8a49444d979f94a59bbb155/System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs#L679):

```
    private bool MatchPattern(string relativePath) {            
        string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(relativePath);            
        if (name != null)
            return PatternMatcher.StrictMatchPattern(filter.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        else
            return false;                
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DP:

```
    public static bool MatchesWildCard(this string s, string wildCard)
    {
        bool[,] dp = new bool[wildCard.Length + 1, s.Length + 1];
        dp[0, 0] = true;
        for(int i = 1; i <= wildCard.Length; i++)
        {
            if (wildCard[i - 1] != '*')
                break;
            for (int j = 0; j <= s.Length; j++)
                dp[i, j] = true;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < wildCard.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
            {
                char sChar = s[j];
                char wChar = wildCard[i];
                
                bool left = dp[i + 1, j];
                bool bottom = dp[i, j + 1];
                bool diag = dp[i, j];

                bool current;
                if (wChar == '*')
                {
                    current = left || diag || bottom;
                }
                else if (wChar == '?')
                {
                    current = diag;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = diag && (wChar == sChar);
                }
                dp[i + 1, j + 1] = current;
            }
        }
        return dp[wildCard.Length, s.Length];
    }
```

The following is the test cases:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestWildCardHelper
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(TestMatchesWildCardDataTrue))]
    public void TestMatchesWildCardTrue(string s, string wildCard)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(WildCardHelper.MatchesWildCard(s, wildCard));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(TestMatchesWildCardDataFalse))]
    public void TestMatchesWildCardFalse(string s, string wildCard)
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(WildCardHelper.MatchesWildCard(s, wildCard));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestMatchesWildCardDataTrue
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new object[]{"",""},
                new object[]{"","*"},
                new object[]{"","**"},
                new object[]{"","***"},
                new object[]{"a","a"},
                new object[]{"a","?"},
                new object[]{"a","a*"},
                new object[]{"a","*a"},
                new object[]{"a","*"},
                new object[]{"a","**"},
                new object[]{"abc","abc"},
                new object[]{"abc","?bc"},
                new object[]{"abc","a?c"},
                new object[]{"abc","ab?"},
                new object[]{"abc","*bc"},
                new object[]{"abc","*c"},
                new object[]{"abc","*"},
                new object[]{"abc","a*c"},
                new object[]{"abc","a*"},
                new object[]{"abc","ab*"},
                new object[]{"abc","a*?"},
                new object[]{"abc","a**"},
                new object[]{"abc","*?"},
                new object[]{"abc","???"},
                new object[]{"abc","?*"},
                new object[]{"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab","*b"},
                new object[]{"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab","a*b"},
                new object[]{"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab","a*"},
                new object[]{"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab","a*a*a**b"},
                new object[]{"abc.xyz.txt","*txt"},
                new object[]{"abc.xyz.txt","*.txt"},
                new object[]{"abc.xyz.txt","abc*.txt"},
                new object[]{"abc.xyz.txt","abc.*.txt"},
            };
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestMatchesWildCardDataFalse
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new object[]{"","a"},
                new object[]{"","?"},
                new object[]{"a",""},
                new object[]{"a","b"},
                new object[]{"abc","a?"},
                new object[]{"a","??"},
                new object[]{"abc","*b"},
                new object[]{"abc","b*"},
                new object[]{"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","*b"},
                new object[]{"abc.xyz.txt","*.ttt"},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version, which supports ** wild card:

```
    static Regex FileMask2Regex(string mask)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(mask);

        // hide wildcards
        sb.Replace("**", "affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-StarStar");
        sb.Replace("*", "affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Star");
        sb.Replace("?", "affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Question");
        sb.Replace("/", "affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Slash");
        sb.Replace("\\", "affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Slash");

        sb = new StringBuilder(Regex.Escape(sb.ToString()));

        // unhide wildcards
        sb.Replace("affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-StarStar", @".*");
        sb.Replace("affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Star", @"[^/\\]*");
        sb.Replace("affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Question", @"[^/\\]");
        sb.Replace("affefa0d52e84c2db78f5510117471aa-Slash", @"[/\\]");

        sb.Append("$");

        // allowed to have prefix
        sb.Insert(0, @"^(?:.*?[/\\])?");

        return new Regex(sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
```

Comment: You could just escape them with `Regex.Escape`, and then search for the escaped backslash first to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

How about using reflection to get access to the function in the .NET framework?

Like this:

```
public class PatternMatcher
{
  public delegate bool StrictMatchPatternDelegate(string expression, string name);
  public StrictMatchPatternDelegate StrictMatchPattern;
  public PatternMatcher()
  {
    Type patternMatcherType = typeof(FileSystemWatcher).Assembly.GetType("System.IO.PatternMatcher");
    MethodInfo patternMatchMethod = patternMatcherType.GetMethod("StrictMatchPattern", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
    StrictMatchPattern = (expression, name) => (bool)patternMatchMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { expression, name });
  }
}

void Main()
{
  PatternMatcher patternMatcher = new PatternMatcher();
  Console.WriteLine(patternMatcher.StrictMatchPattern("*.txt", "test.txt")); //displays true
  Console.WriteLine(patternMatcher.StrictMatchPattern("*.doc", "test.txt")); //displays false
}
```