# How do i check if file end with specific extension then add the file to a List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
if (!files.Contains(file) && file.Contains(textBox2.Text))
   {
     files.Add(file);
   }
```

In textBox2.Text the value is cs or if i type .cs or *.cs
I want that only files with this extensions of cs will be added to the List files.

The second contains: `file.Contains(textBox2.Text)` is wrong since i want to check for the extension and not any place with cs.

Answer (score 9):

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
if (!files.Contains(file) && ext == textBox2.Text)
   {
     files.Add(file);
   }
```

should do it. If you need fancier matching then look here [How to determine if a File Matches a File Mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725341/how-to-determine-if-a-file-matches-a-file-mask)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression to isolate the extension from your text box.

```
\.[^.\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$
```

As long you type "Something.cs" it will return ".cs". If there is no match (like just "cs") you just have to add a dot.

Then you could check if the file extension is equal (Path.GetExtension return the .) to the value calculated before.

Of course if you want that only "cs", ".cs" or "*.cs" works and that "buggedmodule.cs" has a different behavior (filter on the file name and not the extension) it won't work.