# Call RtlIsNameInExpression from .Net code

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, dllimport, windows-console

Because of a lot of [intricacies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/wildcards-in-windows) in [filename patternmatching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=24143) in Windows (and former DOS) I'd like to call [RtlIsNameInExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlisnameinexpression) from my .Net code to make sure my (console) application will behave identical to Windows applications. However, I don't seem to be able to find how to PInvoke this function; I have no idea what the `DllImport` should look like and I am unable to find any examples nor anything useful on [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=RtlIsNameInExpression&namespace=%5BAll%5D).

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**:
I was blind. I was googling `FsRtlIsNameInExpression` where I *should've* been googling `RtlIsNameInExpression` (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409426/call-fsrtlisnameinexpression-from-net-code#comment85820527_49409426)).

Anyway; found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793279/215042) and that seems to work.

Comment: Your `FsRtlIsNameInExpression` link seems to be broken - it sends me to an MSDN error page.

Comment: @MattJones Sorry; fixed the link. I _just_ noticed it seems to be a 'driver' function ([**Fs**RtlIsNameInExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546850(v=vs.85).aspx)) so not userspace... that will be the problem. I should be looking for `RtlIsNameInExpression`. Will start my google journey again...

Comment: Finally found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793279/215042). Will try it.

Comment: Many functions reside in several places, as you can tell from the prototype they both probably have a matching or very similar implementation. Chances are the KM version pays attention to some restrictions that only exist in kernel mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the below code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793279/215042). Posting / answering my own question to make sure it doesn't get lost. All credit to [David Růžička](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6234165/david-r%C5%AF%C5%BEi%C4%8Dka)

```
// UNICODE_STRING for Rtl... method
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct UNICODE_STRING
{
    public ushort Length;
    public ushort MaximumLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string Buffer;

    public UNICODE_STRING(string buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            Length = MaximumLength = 0;
        else
            Length = MaximumLength = unchecked((ushort)(buffer.Length * 2));
        Buffer = buffer;
    }
}

// RtlIsNameInExpression method from NtDll.dll system library
public static class NtDll
{
    [DllImport("NtDll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public extern static bool RtlIsNameInExpression(
        ref UNICODE_STRING Expression,
        ref UNICODE_STRING Name,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        bool IgnoreCase,
        IntPtr Zero
        );
}

public bool MatchMask(string mask, string fileName)
{
    // Expression must be uppercase for IgnoreCase == true (see MSDN for RtlIsNameInExpression)
    UNICODE_STRING expr = new UNICODE_STRING(mask.ToUpper());
    UNICODE_STRING name = new UNICODE_STRING(fileName);

    if (NtDll.RtlIsNameInExpression(ref expr, ref name, true, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        // MATCHES !!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Wildcards are implemented in the filesystem for the [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) system call. Microsoft filesystems will call `FsRtlIsNameInExpression`, or something equivalent, but they don't necessarily use the current system upcase table, which is what you're using here. For example, NTFS stores the upcase table at the time the volume is formatted. In principle it could be different, depending on the Unicode version, but in practice it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also, we don't know what other filesystem device drivers do -- e.g. a driver for an ext3 volume, or a VirtualBox shared folder. But there's a solid case that not complying with the rules (e.g. for `DOS_QM`, `DOS_STAR`, `DOS_DOT`) that `FindFirstFile` and Windows applications expect is a bug.